# How to call ajax in plugin file

Tags: ajax

I am very new to ajax with wordpress . Here i am getting a selected option value in `var test` using bellow function when i alert it its showing a right value.

This `var test` value i have to send using ajax and i want GET this value in PHP variable.

So what i required to call ajax and get script variable value of  `var test`  in php  in  plugin file where i have both bellow function and select box.

JQuery Funtion.

```
jQuery("#time_slot").change(function()
{

var test= time_slot.value;
alert(test);

});
```

Select Box

```
<select name="time_slot" id="time_slot" class="time_slot">
<option value="">Choose a Time</option>
<option value="1:00 - 3:00">01:00 AM-03:00 AM</option>
<option value="3:00 - 5:00">03:00 AM-05:00 AM</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have call ajax using bellow code its working good.
Here i am sending the `variable time` to this page using post `$.post("'. plugins_url().'/woocommerce-booking/gettime.php",`

```
var time=0;
jQuery("#time_slot").change(function()
                                {   
                                time=time_slot.value;
                            $.post("'. plugins_url().'/woocommerce-booking/gettime.php",
                                 {name: time},
                                  function(response){
                                  console.log(response);
                                  }
                                );  
                                 });
```

my gettime.php file will be look like bellow and getting response from my ajax call.

```
<?php session_start();
    echo $name= $_POST["name"];
    file_put_contents("name.txt", $name)

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in wordpress Ajax actions:

Your jquery will look like this:

```
$('#ajax_form').bind('submit', function() {
    var form = $('#ajax_form');
    var data = form.serialize();
    data.action = 'MyPlugin_GetVars'
    $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
        alert(response);           
    });
return false;
```

Your plugin code something like:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_MyPlugin_GetVars", "MyPlugin_GetVars");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_MyPlugin_GetVars", "MyPlugin_GetVars");

function MyPlugin_GetVars(){
    global $wpdb;
    // use $wpdb to do your inserting

    //Do your ajax stuff here
    // You could do include('/wp-content/plugins/test/getvars.php') but you should
    // just avoid that and move the code into this function
}
```

For more info please visit [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: can you tell me the file structure according to question code

Answer (score 0):

please look at below, it may help to you.
Here it is your **PHP** code.

```
<?php

function ajax_enqueuescripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxloadpost', plugins_url().'/your-plugin-name/js/my-ajax.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxloadpost', 'ajax_postajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajax_enqueuescripts);

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_ajaxhandler', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_ajaxhandler', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback(){  
    print_r($_GET);
    die;
}
```

And here it is your JS code. You need to create new JS file and put below code in your new JS file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#time_slot").change(function()
{

    var test= time_slot.value;

jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajax_postajax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_ajaxhandler',
            test : test   
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

For more details, you can check [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: what to do with this /your-plugin-name/js/my-ajax.js  can elaborate it

Comment: You need to put your js code in my-ajax.js(file name of js). So "/your-plugin-name/js/my-ajax.js" will be your path to JS file.

Comment: booking.php is file name where i am getting Jqery value which i have to send in ajax call so where i will put this function ajax_enqueuescripts() { and can create the ja file under the booking.php file and can i put file name of that js file in

Comment: getting error arse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION on this hook line add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajax_enqueuescripts);

Comment: i have done all thing you said in answer but getting above error

Comment: I am using same code as above I posted, but its working fine for me.

Comment: when i add the hooks action on top not showing any error but ajax not calling check the link  and avoid Gender option its not in use direct selct calender and then time http://test.skovian.com/thefoodieclub.com/dine/dine/lunch-at-olive-bistro/

Comment: can i share you the plugin file

Comment: i didnt got your comment can comment again about at admin site

Comment: Hi sanjay, pls get my plugins file from [here](http://zplustechnolab.com/custom-plugin.zip)

Comment: And about that admin site comment, please kindly ignore that.

Comment: my plugin using already this hook add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'my_enqueue_scripts_css' ));
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'my_enqueue_scripts_js' ));

Comment: Where did you display your **select box** at admin side or front side?

Comment: front site for end user

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Your Plugin php page

```
 add_action("wp_ajax_ajax_plugin_call", "ajax_plugin_call_callback"); 
 add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_plugin_call", "ajax_plugin_call_callback");
```

Ajax Function in Php Page

```
function ajax_plugin_call_callback{
   global $wpdb;
   print_r($_POST) ; 
   // write your Php Code
   die;

}
```

Your Javascript Code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#formID').bind('submit', function() { // Form submit Button
      var form_value =  jQuery('#formID'); 
      var form_data = form_value.serialize(); //Serialize the Form 
      form_data['action']='ajax_plugin_call'; // Action 
     jQuery.post('<?php  echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',form_data,function(response){

         // Here is the Ajax Response

       });
    }
 });
```

Please Check this, it will provide you help in WordPress Ajax call in plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please elaborate. Your answer is considered code dumping.

Comment: @engelen hey i have used ajax like var data = {
   current_datedddd: sdfdsfsdf,
   post_id: "'.$duplicate_of.'", 
   action: "call_addon_price1"
   '.$attribute_fields_str.'
   };
  alert(sdfdsfsdf); its posting time value but in function action: "call_addon_price1" i am not able to store in variblle using POST

Comment: can you tell me what is "$attribute_fields_str"?

Comment: @engelen you can check my ajax call  http://test.skovian.com/thefoodieclub.com/dine/dine/lunch-at-olive-bistro/

Comment: Please Try this         add_action("wp_ajax_ajax_call_addon_price1", "call_addon_price1_callback"); 
        add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_call_addon_price1", "call_addon_price1_callback");
        
      function call_addon_price1_callback(){
       try this in your plugin
       print_r($_POST);
       die;
      }

Answer (score 0):

You must first enqueue the script and define the URL. Then you have to create a function for your AJAX callback and add a WordPress action that calls it. Here is a video where I explain it, hope it helps. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7OK-TtNuEc